# HTML5 game - Imported JQuery file will not work

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make a simple game using HTML 5, CSS, and JQuery. However, the imported .js file that I used as a test, "game.js" does not have any effect on the layout of the game (the css code makes the pong paddles blue, but the jquery code is supposed to overwrite and make the paddles red). In my HTML file I referenced 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js' as my jquery source. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Pong</h1>
  </header>
  <div id = "game">
  <div id = "playArea">
    <div id= "paddleA" class="paddle"></div>
    <div id= "paddleB" class="paddle"></div>
    <div id= "ball"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Its like Pong. Exactly like Pong.
  </footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></style>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (styles.css):

```
#playArea{
background: #FFFF99; 
width: 650px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#ball {
background: #990000;
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
left: 320px;
top: 100px;
border-radius: 10px;                
}

.paddle {
background: #66FF99;
left: 50px;
top: 70px;
position: absolute;
width: 30px;
height: 70px;
}

#paddleB {
left: 570px;
}
```

jQuery (game.js):

```
$(function(){
    $("#paddleB").css("top", "100px");
    $("#paddleA").css("top", "60px");
    $(".paddle").css("background", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function(){}` and `$(function(){}` are the same thing, so this might be causing issues. I suggest you try only using one of them.

e.g.

```
$(function(){
    $("#paddleB").css("top", "100px");
    $("#paddleA").css("top", "60px");
    $(".paddle").css("background", "red");
});
```

**EDIT**

Scratch that! You have `</style>` at the end of the `game.js` inclusion rather than `</script>`

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I tried this and it had the same effect. Anything else you would suggest?

Comment: Wow you're right! Probably would have taken me a while to see that, thanks!